# spring boot 1.3 maven module can not autowried

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am using spring boot 1.3, and I have a maven parent project which have two maven module, One I called `demo-web` and another I called `demo-service`.

I need to `demo-web`'s controller can invoke `demo-service`'s method.

my project struct like below.

[image]

My Parent Pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.jiabangougo</groupId>
<artifactId>jiabangougo-demo-parent</artifactId>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<modules>
    <module>jiabangougo-demo-web</module>
    <module>jiabangougo-demo-service</module>
</modules>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.0.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

My `demo-web` pom

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<parent>
    <artifactId>jiabangougo-demo-parent</artifactId>
    <groupId>com.jiabangougo</groupId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<artifactId>jiabangougo-demo-web</artifactId>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.jiabangougo</groupId>
        <artifactId>jiabangougo-demo-service</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

And My `demo-service` POM

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<parent>
    <artifactId>jiabangougo-demo-parent</artifactId>
    <groupId>com.jiabangougo</groupId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<artifactId>jiabangougo-demo-service</artifactId>
```

Here's **ProductController.java**

```
@RestController
public class ProductController {

    @Autowired
    ProductService productService;

    @RequestMapping("/product/{name}")
    Product getByName(String name){
        return productService.findByName(name);
    }

}
```

There is my **ProductService.java**

```
public interface ProductService {
    Product findByName(String name);
}
```

And my **ProductServiceImpl.java**

```
@Service
public class ProductServiceImpl implements ProductService {

    @Autowired
    private ProductRepository productRepository;

    @Override
    public Product findByName(String name) {
        return productRepository.findByName(name);
    }
}
```

Because this is just a test code, very simple. But when I start tomcat in IDEA14, I got an error.

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.jiabangougo.service.service.ProductService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

There error log show me that : `ProductService` **cannot be autowired by spring boot**.

When I use spring boot 1.2.5, there's no compile error, but boot 1.3 have. I don't know what's wrong with this. Thanks.

the full error stack is here:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'productController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.jiabangougo.service.service.ProductService com.jiabangougo.web.controller.ProductController.productService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.jiabangougo.service.service.ProductService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:838) ~[spring-context-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537) ~[spring-context-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118) ~[spring-boot-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:1.3.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:752) [spring-boot-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:1.3.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.doRun(SpringApplication.java:347) [spring-boot-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:1.3.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:295) [spring-boot-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:1.3.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1112) [spring-boot-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:1.3.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1101) [spring-boot-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:1.3.0.RELEASE]
at com.jiabangougo.web.Application.main(Application.java:14) [classes/:na]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:140) [idea_rt.jar:na]

    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.jiabangougo.service.service.ProductService com.jiabangougo.web.controller.ProductController.productService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.jiabangougo.service.service.ProductService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:573) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
... 22 common frames omitted


        Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.jiabangougo.service.service.ProductService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1373) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1119) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1014) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:545) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
... 24 common frames omitted
```

Comment: I am missing a `WebApplicationInitializer` or a `web.xml` in your question. Did you add a component scan for package `com.jiabangogou.service` too?

Comment: @ksokol spring boot application do not need web.xml

Comment: @ksokol I use ComponentScan annotation, still got the same error

Comment: Sorry. I meant [`SpringBootServletInitializer`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-create-a-deployable-war-file).

Comment: For troubleshooting purpose run `mvn package` and check whether there is service impl class inside war.

Comment: @ksokol mvn package show no error......

Comment: Spring says that it cannot find impl class for `com.jiabangougo.service.service.ProductService`. There is a double `service` in your package. Is this right? Mabye you can share the project with us?

Comment: @ksokol how to share? github?

Comment: can you try @ComponentScan for com.jiabangougo.service.service ?and also could you also show the pom <modules> tag in parent and its sequence..Thanks.

Comment: @diligent Yes. Github or Bitbucket

Comment: No qualifying bean of type `com.what.Ever` means that the impl isn't picked up as bean. Try printing something from it's constructor to see if it's instantiated. It shouldn't. It must be on classpath or there would have been a classloader exception. This should not work in 1.2.X either because the default behavior is to scan only sub packages of the application class. But adding @ComponentScan to an active configuration class (e.g. the application class) should fix that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to configure this project locally and after some fixes it works.

ProductController:

```
    import com.example.stackoverflow.domain.Product;
    import com.example.stackoverflow.service.ProductService;
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
    import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

    import java.util.List;

    @RestController
    @EnableAutoConfiguration
    @ComponentScan("com.example.stackoverflow")
    public class ProductController {

        @Autowired
        ProductService productService;

        @RequestMapping(value = "/product/{name}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
        Product getByName(@PathVariable String name) {
            return productService.findByName(name);
        }

        @RequestMapping(value = "/products", method = RequestMethod.GET)
        List<Product> getProducts() {
            return productService.getAllProducts();
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
            SpringApplication.run(ProductController.class, args);
        }
    }
```

ProductService:

```
    import com.example.stackoverflow.domain.Product;
    import java.util.List;

    public interface ProductService {
        Product findByName(String name);
        List<Product> getAllProducts();
    }
```

ProductServiceImpl:

```
    import com.example.stackoverflow.domain.Product;
    import com.example.stackoverflow.repository.ProductRepository;
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
    import java.util.List;

    @Component
    public class ProductServiceImpl implements ProductService {

        @Autowired
        private ProductRepository productRepository;

        public Product findByName(String name) {
            return productRepository.findByName(name);
        }

        public List<Product> getAllProducts() {
            return productRepository.getAllProducts();
        }
    }
```

ProductRepository:

```
    import com.example.stackoverflow.domain.Product;
    import java.util.List;

    public interface ProductRepository {
        Product findByName(String name);
        List<Product> getAllProducts();
    }
```

ProductRepositoryImpl:

```
    import com.example.stackoverflow.domain.Product;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
    import java.util.Arrays;
    import java.util.List;

    @Component
    public class ProductRepositoryImpl implements ProductRepository {

        private List<Product> products = Arrays.asList(
                new Product("Coca Cola", "drink"),
                new Product("Pepsi", "drink"));

        public Product findByName(String name) {
            for (Product product : products) {
                if (product.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(name)) {
                    return product;
                }
            }
            return null;
        }

        public List<Product> getAllProducts() {
            return products;
        }
    }
```

Product:

```
    import java.util.Objects;

    public class Product {
        private String name;
        private String category;

        public Product(String name, String category) {
            this.name = name;
            this.category = category;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public String getCategory() {
            return category;
        }

        public void setCategory(String category) {
            this.category = category;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object o) {
            if (this == o) return true;
            if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
            Product product = (Product) o;
            return Objects.equals(name, product.name) &&
                    Objects.equals(category, product.category);
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            return Objects.hash(name, category);
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Product{" +
                    "name='" + name + '\'' +
                    ", category='" + category + '\'' +
                    '}';
        }
    }
```

Parent POM:

```
<modules>
        <module>demo-web</module>
        <module>demo-service</module>
    </modules>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>1.3.0.RELEASE</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

After running applicetion from ProductController you can check these urls:

```
    http://localhost:8080/product/pepsi

    http://localhost:8080/products
```

You can also check source code on my [github page](https://github.com/ayurchuk/stackoverflow/tree/master/stackoverflow-pocs/stackoverflow-spring-boot-maven)